# how to check if selected paragraph is in a right column or in a left column in a two column paragraph word VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make a macro that adds a text box in the right of a paragraph in the right columns, and in the left of a paragraph in the left columns.

I'm using  page columns

I'd like to know how to make a macro that checks if the selected text is in the right column or left in the left column?
I haven't fount the code to check that

Comment: Are you using table columns, or page columns?

Comment: @macropod I'm using page columns

Comment: @braX I couldn't find in the documentation how to check that